# Binary file writing the same data format in VB6 and C#

Tags: c#, file-io, vb6, binary

I have found an issue. I have to write binary files by using VB6 and C#. When I wrote same set of variables as mentioned below, both output differs. I can guess, the way they represent the string is different in C# and VB6. I just wanted to know is there any way to make both writing similar. Because there are timesI may need to write the same contents by C# and VB

VB6

```
nFileNum = FreeFile
stringVal = ""
stringVal2 = "Hello"
i = 25
sFilename = "C:\Temp\fromVB.bin"
Open sFilename For Binary As #nFileNum
    Put #nFileNum, , stringVal
    Put #nFileNum, , stringVal2
    Put #nFileNum, , i
Close #nFileNum
```

C#

```
    const string fileName = @"C:\Temp\fromC#.bin";
    string stringVal = "";
    string stringVal2 = "Hello";
    int i = 25;

    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        writer.Write(stringVal);
        writer.Write(stringVal2);
        writer.Write(i);
    }
```

Comment: Why did you expect `Put` to write the identical contents as `BinaryWriter`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders. I accept your argument, but I want to make sure. Binary files written by different types of programming languages (C#,VB). Will it be different always? Or is there anyway to make similar

Comment: It has nothing to do with the programming language. That's totally different code.

Comment: C# and VB .Net both 'compile' into the EXACT same executable (which - for completeness - is not machine language but an intermediate code common to all .Net languages).

Comment: unfortunately I am doing a migration from VB6 to C#.Net. So I have to write some binary files by using C# and sometimes by VB6. I just wanted to compare. That's why asked this question

Comment: Is there any ways to make both VB6 and C# binary writing similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's hardly the same code. You shouldn't be using the old File Number -based IO in VB.Net any more. That API still exists for the sole purpose of making it easier to port code to .Net from VB6. VB.Net should be using the same API as the C# code. All the more so if you want matching results:

```
Const fileName As String = "C:\Temp\fromVB.bin"
Dim stringVal As String = ""
Dim stringVal2 As String = "Hello"
Dim i As Integer = 25

Using writer As New BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    writer.Write(stringVal)
    writer.Write(stringVal2)
    writer.Write(i)
End Using
```

Comment: @Rambo Ah. In that case, we need to fix the tags on your question.

Comment: Thanks for tag fixing. But I just wanted to know, Is there any ways to make it similar (both VB6 and C# binary writing)

Comment: My advice is to add a VB.Net class library project to your solution, and use that project exclusively for reading/writing your old files. Then you can use the same old File Number Get/Put mechanism... as I said, it's what they still exist for. Then you'll be able to call into your class library project from C#.

Comment: Alternatively, you can write a program in VB.Net to read files using the old API's and write them back using the new API, to convert them for use from .Net.

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember the exact format of the data written by VB6 (and I'm too lazy to test) but you may need to write out the string length and the string itself seperately.
You should be able to see the exact format using a hex editor to view the files.

Comment: Ah, It will be a good idea. Let me try and share the feedback